# Mustache - isset

Tags: php, mustache

How can I check if a variable is set in mustache? Like:

```
<?php if(isset($foo) && isset($bar)): ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{{#varname}}
  {{varname}}
{{/varname}}
```

see http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html, first example

Comment: It's kind of a long syntax because of the closing (endif is better in .php), but thanks!